# $p$ cohomological dimension of profinite groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime and $S$ is any finite set containing the primes above $p$ and the Archimedean primes. Does there exist *any* number field $K$ such that $\textrm{Gal}(K_S/ K_{cyc})$ has $p$-cohomological dimension 1?

Here $K_S$ is the maximal unramified extension of $K$ outside $S$ and $K_{cyc}$ is the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $K$.